# In a tree-sitter grammar, how do I match a non-delimited list of values in a non-associative way?

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, treesitter

For example, consider the following grammar:

```
source_file: $ => $._expression,

_expression: $ => choice(
  $.identifier,
  $.operator
),

identifier: $ => /\w*[A-Za-z]\w*/,

operator: $ => seq(
  repeat1(seq($._expression, '\\X')),
  $._expression
)
```

So if I have the input string `a \X b \X c \X d`, I want it to match as:

```
(source_file
  (operator
    (identifier)
    (identifier)
    (identifier)
    (identifier)))
```

However, the only way I can actually get this behavior is to do the following:

```
operator: $ => choice(
  $._operator_2,
  $._operator_3,
  ...
),

_operator_2: $ => prec(1, seq(
  $._expression, '\\X', $._expression)
),

_operator_3: $ => prec(2, seq(
  $._expression, '\\X', $._expression, '\\X', $._expression)
),

...
```

So I have to hardcode all the expression lengths with precedence increasing as the length increases, and can't figure out how to write a catch-all `_operator_n` rule. How do I accomplish this? Some combination of specifying a conflict then assigning dynamic precedence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that this question is a bit stale at this point, but I stumbled across it as I was in the process of learning `tree-sitter` myself and it seemed like an interesting challenge.

Based on the expected output provided, it appears that the intent of the `operator` expression is to consume *all* expressions that are separated by `\X` tokens. The grammar is ambiguous because it defines the `operator` expression itself as one of the expressions that could be consumed by an `operator` expression. As a result, it is impossible for the parser to figure out how it should group the expression sequence.

You can convince `tree-sitter` to generate a valid parser by applying precedence and associativity, but the best you can accomplish with this is to force the parser to break the sequence up into a series of `operator` expressions where each expression has at most one `\X` operator token. The `operator` rule is a visible node so, instead of the expected result, you end up with something like the following (for a right-associative operator):

```lisp
(source_file
  (operator
    (operator
      (operator
        (identifier)
        (identifier))
      (identifier))
    (identifier)))
```

However, the expected result indicates that the `operator` expression should *never* nest at all, but should produce a single `operator` containing a list of all the delimited expressions. The implication is that the `\X` tokens aren't actually delimiting *any expression*, as currently defined, but rather any expression *other than* another `operator` expression.

Therefore, the simplest solution to the ambiguity seems to be to separate the expressions into two types: the `operator` expression, and all other "non-operator" expressions. You can then define the `operator` expression so that it only repeats the non-operator expressions. In my testing, the following grammar rules will produce the expected output.

```js
source_file: $ => $._expression,

_expression: $ => choice(
  $.operator,
  $._non_operator_expression,
),

_non_operator_expression: $ => choice(
  $.identifier,
  // [maybe others]
),

operator: $ => seq(
  repeat1(seq($._non_operator_expression, '\\X')),
  $._non_operator_expression,
)
```